# spreadsheet.values.get returns "#name?"

Tags: flutter, google-sheets-api

We have a Google Sheet where cells contain a UTC time.  The time is calculated using the moment library, based on a timezone value and DateTime string.  The cell formula is `=concat(toUtcString(AP27,$M27),"Z")`

The flutter app uses `'package:googleapis/sheets/v4.dart';` and retrieves the spreadsheet values using

```dart
  sheetApi.spreadsheets.values
            .get('xxxxxxx', 'A:AQ',
                majorDimension: 'ROWS')
```

Normally (>95%) this function returns values as expected, with multiple rows and values in rows comma-separated.

Some of the time, often in the first request after start-up, the returned values for the UTC times are `?NAME#`.

I have not found a consistent sequence that reproduces this.  There are also several scripts attached to the sheet `onOpen(e)` and `onFormSubmit(e)`.  Is there a conflict between these scripts running and accessing the sheet via the api?

Thanks to all.

Comment: Are the values that the api is getting being created at the same time they are requested? Have you tried to check if the result is `?NAME#` to wait and make the request again after some time?

Comment: I do not think the values are being created at the same time.  This can happen in the middle of the night when there is no editing on the spreadsheet. Retrying seems to get into another set of issues - how many times, etc.  Thank  you for your interest.

Comment: Could it be that the values on those cells are formatted in some way? Could you share a reproducible example?